# Replace kubernetes yaml environment variables in Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, rancher

I have an azure devops pipeline that I'm using to deploy a kubernetes project to rancher. In my k8s `deployment.yaml` file I have environment variables defined like this:

```
      containers:
        - name: frontend
          env:
          - name: GIT_HASH
            value: dummy_value
```

I want to be able to replace the `GIT_HASH` with a value created in the azure yml pipeline. Specifically, I have a script to get a git commit e.g:

```
   - task: Bash@3
      displayName: Set the short git hash as a variable
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          short_hash=$(git rev-parse --short=7 HEAD)
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=git-hash;]$short_hash"
```

And I want to be able to inject this value into kubernetes as the `GIT_HASH`. Is there a way to do this?  I've tried using the `qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3` but can't get it to work.

Comment: Have you considered using Helm or Kustomize to template your deployment manifests instead of relying on token replacement?

Comment: `replacetokens` should works, can you share what exactly you did? and I agree with Daniel, you need to consider use Helm.

Comment: Yep, ended up using kustomise as @DanielMann suggested - worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

### Posting comment as the community wiki answer for better visibility.

---

Have you considered using Helm or Kustomize to template your deployment manifests instead of relying on token replacement?

More information can be found on [official Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes-manifest?view=azure-devops)